# How to properly convert unix timestamp into datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I have a little problem on a `Unix Timestamp` conversion in `DateTime`.

This is the `Timestamp`: `1521932400`

I want convert it in `DateTime`, so I wrote this code:

```
 public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
 {
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);
    return dtDateTime;
 }
```

essentially I declare a `DateTime` and then add to that the value of the `Timestamp`, so in this case I'll get: `24/03/2018 23:00:00` but I should get: `25/03/2018 00:00:00`.

What I did wrong?

Comment: According to https://www.epochconverter.com/ you get the correct result....

Comment: Unix timestamp is UTC. In UTC, there is no daylight savings time, but it does exists in GMT. Perhaps that's the source of your confusion.

Comment: See `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`, `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds`.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved. I need to convert the `DateTime` returned from the conversion in my timezone, so I use:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);

    //Convert in my timezone
    TimeZoneInfo timeInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
    DateTime userTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dtDateTime, timeInfo);

    return userTime;
}
```